# Liferay Pagination not working

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created MVC portlet. In doView method I get the custom list(custom) based on the current login user.

```
@Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse){
List<LeadPojo> leadpojoli = new ArrayList<LeadPojo>();
LeadList lead_list = new LeadList();
leadpojoli = lead_list.getRecords(themeDisplay.getUserId()+"");
renderRequest.setAttribute("all_lead", leadpojoli);
super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

In view.jsp I created "**liferay-ui:search-container**" with delta 5. When I click "**Next**" or "**Previous**" it fetching next 5 records and it is working fine in the **view.jsp**.

Now user select the "**Edit**" option from the "**Actions**".Now get the current record id and calling the editRecord method[In this method I fetching two more lists(contact and activity) based on the  selected record] from the MVC class and then loading into an other "**edit.jsp**" with respective lists, object and variables.

**In "edit.jsp" also have two liferay-ui:search-container's and when I click 'next' or 'previous' buttons from the 'liferay-ui:search-container' in the "edit.jsp" it going back to previous page i.e doview method is executed.**

How to fetch the next set of records in the **liferay-ui:search-container** form the "edit.jsp". Two **liferay-ui:search-container**'s showing the total count of the list but not fetching the next set of records.

```
private void editRecord(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response,String backURL) throws IOException {
     String recordId = ParamUtil.getString(request,'selectedId');
    List<LeadActivity> leadactivityli = new ArrayList<LeadActivity>();
    LeadProcess call = new LeadProcess();
    leadactivityli = call.getList(recordId);

    List<ContactPojo> allcon = new ArrayList<ContactPojo>();
    ContactList conli = new ContactList();
    allcon = conli.getContactList(recordId);
           request.setAttribute("allcontacts", allcon); 

            request.setAttribute("edit_leadactivity", leadactivityli);
            response.setRenderParameter("mvcPath","/html/Edit.jsp");

    }
```

**edit.jsp**

```
<%
LeadPojo leadobj = (LeadPojo) request.getAttribute("editlead");
List<LeadActivity> leadactli = (List<LeadActivity>)request.getAttribute("edit_leadactivity");       
List<ContactPojo> allcontacts = (List<ContactPojo>)request.getAttribute("allcontacts"); 
 int notesize =0;
    try{
        notesize = leadactli.size();
    }catch(Exception e){}

%>
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="No Progress Notes Were Found" rowChecker="<%= new RowChecker(renderResponse) %>" iteratorURL="<%= itURL %>">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%= ListUtil.subList(leadactli,searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" total="<%= notesize %>">  
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>  
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.axxonet.LeadActivity" modelVar="leadview" >         
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter name="recordid" value="<%= leadview.getId()%>"></liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter>  
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter name="lead_id" value="<%= leadview.getLead_id()%>"></liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter>  
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Subject"  value="<%= leadview.getSubject()%>">       
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>      
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Visit Note" value="<%= leadview.getCompany_Account()%>">     
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
      <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Date" value="<%=leadview.getPersonalVisit() %>">   
      </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>        
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Created By" value="<%=leadview.getCreated_by()%>"/>              
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp align="right" path="/html/leadactivity.jsp" />      
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator  />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not saying to your portlet class where have to redirect when you click on `Next` button in `edit.jsp`, so by default it redirect to `view.jsp` and execute doView(). Try to use a [custom iteratorURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130292/liferay-search-container-pagination) to achieve this.

Furthermore i'd like to point out that you are apparently managing the entire list even if the results are paginated (so it is just a "front-end pagination"): i hope the list won't grow too much.

Answer (score 0):

Set one parameter `redirect` in your `<portlet:renderURL>`  and set its value as per page you will render.

Now get the `redirect` paramter in render method of  your portlet class.

Then compare it with value you set in `<portlet:renderURL>`. If return true then get your recordId here and then get two according to this recordId and set attributes.

And then return the page path like '/html/edit.jsp' . using include method or return string if you are using SPRING MVC or MVCRenderCommand in in liferay 7.